# Customisable Design Templates

Tags: print-design, software-recommendation

What is the best system/application to create documents (e.g. PDF Brochures, JPG flyers, posters etc.) so that a client can edit the text content whilst still limiting certain things which they cannot touch (i.e. a logo or image).

Comment: I wouldn't supply such files to clients. It's like my accountant giving me a spreadsheet and trusting me to use it correctly... just prone to errors.

Comment: Best is not defined

Answer (score 1):

InDesign with a locked 'Artwork' layer the client doesn't need to touch and an unlocked 'Text' layer where they can replace with custom content. You can further secure the locked layer by actually locking all the objects on it, so it works like a double lock. An inexperienced client will have some trouble getting past this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think it really boils down to what your client is comfortable using. 
Most clients usually won't have the Adobe suite. There have been times where I've designed in InDesign - where I'm comfortable creating - and subsequently rebuilt the document in Word for a client. e.g. letterheads, a short newsletter. Most designers will shun this but you can be quite precise with Word when you know what you are doing.

In any case, I would **flatten the artwork and use the most high-quality/low size file** I could produce, likely a PDF. If you can lock it on a layer, even better.

Illustrator also has a template mode on layers that is a bit more buried in the layer options, however, whatever is in template mode normally does not print.